# How to add columns repeatedly into a dataframe in python3

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm currently writing a function to simulate the wealth in the coin flip game. f is the percentage I will invest my money(AUM) into this game. I simulate 10000 steps, at every step, I want to include the AUM number into my wealth list.Thus, at the end of the 10000 steps, I will have a list containing 10001 numbers (includes AUM =100). In the end, I want to have a dataframe (10001*100) with each column corresponding to a wealth series with different f (column names) invested. But my below codes keeps poping errors:

raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

or

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Could anyone help me how to solve this issue (add 100 series, each with 10001 elements, into a dataframe)? Many thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
wealth = [100] ### initial AUM
def path(f): 
    global AUM
    global wealth
    for j in range(10000):  ### one simulation with 10,000 steps
        if Ber_Dist_V [j] == 1: ### Bernouli distribution
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + win)
        else:
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + lose)
        wealth.append(AUM)
    wealth = pd.Series(wealth)
    df[f]=wealth

weight = np.linspace(0, 1, 100,endpoint=False).tolist()
for f in weight:
    path_weight(f)
```

Comment: There seems to be lots missing from you code. What is AUM, Ber_Dist_V, path_weight etc

Comment: You are getting the the `ValueError` because your `wealth` list is of very different lengths. It's not really necessary to turn it into a series to set it as one of the columns of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the the `ValueError` because your `wealth` list is of very different lengths. It's not really necessary to turn it into a series to set it as one of the columns of your dataframe. Your internal logic isn't very transparent, but resetting the list (so `wealth` always has a constant length) should fix it I think. I would suggest something analogous to the below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
def path(f): 
    global AUM
    wealth = [100] # Resets `wealth` with each invocation of `path()`.
    for j in range(10000):  ### one simulation with 10,000 steps
        if Ber_Dist_V [j] == 1: ### Bernouli distribution
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + win)
        else:
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + lose)
        wealth.append(AUM)
    df[f] = wealth

weight = np.linspace(0, 1, 100,endpoint=False).tolist()
for f in weight:
    path_weight(f)
```

However, if you wanted to make your code faster (and seeing as you know `wealth` would be l0001 elements long, you could prefill it at instantiation and just update the elements instead. That should be much faster than using `.append()`. I'd write it like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
def path(f): 
    global AUM
    wealth = [100] + [0]*10000 # Resets `wealth` with each invocation of `path()`. Prefills wealth with `0`.
    for j in range(1, 10001):  ### one simulation with 10,000 steps
        if Ber_Dist_V [j] == 1: ### Bernouli distribution
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + win)
        else:
            AUM = AUM * (1-f) + AUM * f * (1 + lose)
        wealth[i] = AUM    # Faster than using `.append()`.
    df[f] = wealth

weight = np.linspace(0, 1, 100,endpoint=False).tolist()
for f in weight:
    path_weight(f)
```

Comment: Great Thanks! It works! I'm still think about where is wrong. In my original codes, my logic is that every time I run my self-defined path() function, in the loop, a series/list called wealth will be created with the starting value 100 and then be included in the empty DataFrame as columns.  Then a new wealth series/list is created and added into the DataFrame and so on. I don't quite understand why the wealth Series is of different length.

Comment: One more question is that, since now I have the dataframe with each column corresponding to a wealth series, like 1st column is the wealth series starting with $100 and invest 0% with 10001 steps, the last column is the wealth series starting with $100 and invest 100% with 10001 steps. Is there any method that I can have a plot with 100 lines(each line corresponding to a wealth column/series) plotted in one graph with starting value 100 and each wealth number at each step point?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured it out:                                                                                            
for i in weight: 
    plt.plot(np.arange(10001), df[i])

Comment: @Rick if you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.